# Replace in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Can someone please explain this to me.

```
string = "I hope 1111 someone 1111 will 1111 help me."
newString = string.replace("1111", "Hello")
print newString
```

Gives me this: "I hope Hello someone Hello will Hello help me."

My inputfile consists of 1 keyword per line.

```
for line in inputfile.readlines():
    newString += string.replace("1111", line)

print newString
```

Gives me this: "I hope Hello (newline) somone Hello (newline) will Hello (newline) help me"
How can i prevent my script from creating a new line for every hit on replace when in a for loop?  I'm guessing the problem is that at the first hit the for loop is "true" and it starts over again, so maybe i need a while loop inside the for loop?  Can someone show me how to do this?

Keyword.txt
green
blue

I want it to look like this:
I hope green someone green will green help me.
I hope blue someone blue will blue help me.

Thx.

Comment: Check if you don't have new lines in your input file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are just confused because you still have the newlines from the file in your output. Try this instead:

```
for line in inputfile.readlines():
    newString += string.replace('1111', line.strip())

print newString
```

Each `line` in the file is (naturally) followed by a line break. `strip` removes leading and trailing whitespace by default (including `'\n'`, `'\t'`).